# Structural Induction with Propositional Variables

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

I've been stuck on this question and I'm confused as to how to approach it:

> Let $G$ be a set defined as follows:
>
> - if $x$ is a propositional variable, then $x \in G$;
> - if $f_1,f_2 \in G$, then $\lnot f_1 \in G$, and $(f_1 \land f_2) \in G$;
> - nothing else belongs to $G$.
>
> For a formula $f \in G$, let $c_{not}(f)$ be the number of occurrences
>   of $\lnot$ in $f$, and $c_{and}(f)$ be the number of occurrences of
>   $\land$ in $f$. Let $H = \{f \in G : c_{not}(f) = c_{and}(f)\}$.
>   That is, $H$ is the set of formulas in $G$ with equal number of $\lnot$'s
>   and $\land$'s.
>
> Prove that for any formula $f \in G$,
>   there is a formula $f'$ such that $f' \in H$ and $f'$ and $f$
>   are logically equivalent.

Comment: Don't link to images; it's considered bad form here. Also, you need to say what you have tried. (This is not a we-do-your-homework service.)

Comment: It's the approach I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach for part of the inductive part.

Suppose $\neg f$ is a formula in $G$. $f$ has a formula $f'$ which has the same number of $\neg$s as $\wedge$s. Now, you need to find a formula equivalent to $\neg f'$ with the same number of *visible* $\neg$s as visible $\wedge$s. (In the formula $\neg f'$, you have one visible $\neg$ and no visible $\wedge$s; I'm not counting the $\neg$s and $\wedge$s in $f'$, which balance by induction.)

Now, you just need to come up with a bunch of equivalent formulas to $\neg f'$; I'll try a few: $\neg\neg\neg f'$ (nope), $\neg f' \wedge \neg f'$ (nope), $\neg (f'\wedge f')$ ... and we have a winner! It has one visible $\neg$ and one visible $\wedge$, and since the $\neg$s and $\wedge$s balance in $f'$, we have the equivalent formula for $\neg f$ which is in $H$ as well.

Now you do $f\wedge g$.